# Possible to make dynamic Stripe Webhooks URL?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a Nuxt app with [Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/email.html#programmatic-usage) on the backend. I'm working through using Sendgrid to email users who have purchased a product with a download link. I've got it mostly working, however I want to know if I can create a Stripe webhook URL with dynamic query parameters. This is what I currently have as a hard-coded webhook URL:

```
https://<my-domain.com>/orders/send_download?order_id=fu8ds9fu2ojsdlifjsl&email=test@gmail.com
```

When I receive that in my controller action, it successfully fires off an email, however I need both `order_id` and `email` query parameters to be dynamic. Is this possible, or is there an even better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Rather than making the URL dynamic, it's easier to use [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) in Stripe's API and then read those values from the event objects. Which object you want to set that on depends on which events you are looking at in the webhook endpoints. For example: if you're reading `payment_intent.successful` events, set the metadata on your PaymentIntents.

Comment: Fantastic! Would metadata be available in the `charge.succeeded` event?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @taintedzodiac I was able to figure it out! By including metadata with the charge, it automatically is sent over via the webhook. In this way, rather than using query parameters, I could extract the data that I needed from within the request body (`request.body.data.object.metadata`).

Comment: I'm literally trying to do the same thing. Can you please some demo code or reference how meta data is being changed according to the query parameters?